# Structural navigation not updating for publishing site

Tags: navigation, publishing-site, public-website

We have a SharePoint 2016 instance that had been upgraded all the way from MOSS 2007, SP 2010, and SP 2013. As far as we can tell the upgrade process has always gone smoothly. However, with SP 2016, we are finding that our publishing site is not publishing changes we make to any of our navigation. All other types of publishing works as it should. We do have a large number of items in the Pages library, and we do hide a lot of nodes and customize the navigation a fair amount.

Not sure how to proceed here - any tips on what to look at? Note that this is the old-school content deployment feature we're using, not the new cross-site publishing.